# How to retrieve intersection from three or four tables in Mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have tables that contain common column.

- A : car, **banana**, monkey
- B : **banana**, dragon, snail
- C : shoes, socks, **banana**

As you can see, column **banana** is the common column. Same name, same data type, (int).

And I want to do some search work span these table.

For example,

1. In A table, I want to find the rows that contains keyword 'Toyota' in column 'car'.
2. In B table, keyword 'evil snail' in column 'snail'
3. ....

Like this.

Then, I'd like to retrieve the value of **banana** fields through two methods :

1. From the found rows of all tables
2. banana that can be found in found row in all tables.

So despite I can't even sketch about solution, two sql line is needed...

I kept think almost eight hours to solve this problem but only headache is get worsen..

I wonder someone could help this out...

Comment: What have you tried with regard to mysql `JOIN` syntax?  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html  What is a sample schema of the tables you are working with?

Comment: Thank you so much for replying my question!! I can't figure a single clue with my knowledge... I'll draw some schema and post with imgur link, please hold on a second!!

Comment: http://imgur.com/CxE9iqH

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To find all the A that contains the key word 'Toyota' in 'car' do:

```
SELECT * FROM A WHERE car like '%Toyota%';
```

Same for B and C. You should notice that the like is use in the case where we are checking if the column contains the value. To make an exact match you should use the equal to sign e.g. car='Toyota'.

For your second query type you want a result which is a dis-junctive in nature. So you should query each table and unite the result like:

```
SELECT a.banana FROM A a where a.banana=[VALUE] 
UNION
SELECT b.banana FROM B b where b.banana=[VALUE]
UNION
SELECT c.banana FROM C c where c.banana=[VALUE];
```

Comment: Thank you so much for answer!!! Do you mind if I test your code and left some feedback?

Comment: Ok @humanresoursuck, you can. Read more on sql querying, and vote up my answer.

Comment: Thanks. I finally figure out other method but yours was helpful, too.